# What is the purpose of this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I was playing around with a Python-based HTML parser and parsed Stackoverflow. The parser puked on a line with

```
HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: bad end tag: "</'+'scr'+'ipt>", at line 649, column 29
```

The error points to the following lines of javascript in the site's source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<s'+'cript lang' + 'uage="jav' + 'ascript" src=" [...] ">'); 
    document.write('</'+'scr'+'ipt>');
</script>
```

([...] replace a long link, which is removed for simplicity)

Out of curiosity, is there a specific reason for what looks to me like artificial 'obfuscation' of the code, i.e. why use the document.write method to concatenate all the chopped up strings?

Comment: The `"</script>"` needs to be chopped up to avoid the HTML parser assuming it's the end of the script block. Not sure why the other stuff is, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's to fight adblockers.

```
... + 'uage="jav' + 'ascript" src="http://ads.stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Yeah, this looks like it because it's in the ad section of the page.  And they even obfuscated the div class name to not sound ad-like. :)

Answer (score 2):

It has been written in that way to avoid the browser thinks it's the closing tag for `<script>`, which would cause some problems.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the top line is chopped up, though.

Comment: Because you cannot write a tag `<script>` inside another one.

Comment: The browser doesn't care what's inside a `<script>` tag - it just ignores everything from that point on until it sees the magic characters '<', '/', 's', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'p', 't', '>'.

Comment: The '<script>' tag is probably zapped because it upsets the syntax highlighting in whatever editor/IDE they are using.

Comment: That is not exact; the browser takes what is inside the tags <script></script>, and passes it to the JavaScript parser, which would not understand the text <script> it would find. As it is not written between quotes, it would not be even interpreted as a string. Browsers are not supposed to handle indented script tags, and they don't handle them.

Answer (score 1):

When the HTML parser encounters `document.write('</script>');`, it thinks it has found the end of the enclosing `<script>` tag. Breaking the tag up stops the parser from recognising the closing tag.

The other way I've seen this achieved is by escaping the slash, i.e. `document.write('<\/script>');`.

The *correct* way to do this is either:

- Enclose the body of the script in a `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` block (if serving XHTML), or
- Put the script in an external file, or
- Use the DOM API instead (i.e. create a script node and append that to the document head)

Comment: CDATA blocks won't help you here. Not if document is served and rendered as HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps its there to stop programs that search specifically for script tags.  Ad blockers, for example, look for script tags and object tags.

Comment: Funny how the most upvoted answer and the most downvoted answer are the same in this question. :)